# Excel Como fazer para descobrir o endereço da celula atual

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho uma coluna na minha tabela onde coloco a data de chegada de um produto.
Eu gostaria de criar uma formatação condicional(colocar a celula em vermelho) quando faltassem 15 dias ou menos para o produto chegar.

A fórmula que usei foi `=$B$7-HOJE()<=15`

O problema é que preciso que a linha, no caso "7", seja variável, quer dizer, deve ser o número da linha em que a célula se encontra.
É possível fazer isso?
Agradeço pela ajuda.

Comment: Não sei se percebi bem, mas este link: [http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13780/] acho que tem o que tu queres fazer.

Comment: Já tentou tirando o '$' do número da linha? =$B7-HOJE()<=15

Comment: @ValderíLeandro funcionou. Muito obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selecione a célula onde deseja aplicar a regra de formatação e clique em "Conditional Formatting".

Escolha, "Manage Rules".

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Certifique-se de que não existam outras regras que possam conflitar.

Neste exemplo, está vazio, então apenas criaremos uma nova regra "New Rule..."

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Escolha a opção "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No campo "Format values where this formula is true", digite a seguinte fórmula

```
=B7<=TODAY()-15
```

<sub>*Tenha cuidado com as teclas direcionais do teclado pois as teclas LEFT e RIGHT automaticamente navegam entre as células e insere suas respectivas referências no campo da fórmula.</sub>

Após adicionar a fórmula, clique no botão "Format..."

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para esse teste, vamos modificar a cor da célula apenas

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após definir a formatação, clique em OK

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na tela seguinte, clique em "Apply" e "OK"

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No momento que clicar em "Apply", a formatação já é aplicada.

Para extender a regra para outras células, basta copiar e colar.

Para o caso de células com valores já existentes, utilize o comando "Paste Especial" e escolha "Formatting". Isso copiará apenas a regra de formatação.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]